# Pivot Pie Chart: Display Percentage relative to total

Tags: excel

I have a table, in which I got a column A. column A consists of a bunch of integers. As well as a Column B, consisting of 3 different Strings.

Based on that table I got a pivot table with 3 rows based on the B column, each row containing the sum of values from the A column corresponding to the B column.

Example:

This is the table:

| B | A |
| --- | --- |
| String1 | 1 |
| String1 | 34 |
| String2 | 4 |
| String2 | 3 |
| String3 | 22 |
| String3 | 7 |

This is the pivot table:

| Rowname | Sum of A |
| --- | --- |
| String1 | 35 |
| String2 | 7 |
| String3 | 29 |

With this I'd like to create a pivot cake chart, displaying the percentage or each "String" in relation to the total value. My approach so far was trying to add a formula to the initial table, which divides current A to SUM([A]) but this doesn't seem to give me the right result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by "pivot cake" you mean a pie chart (*shudder*), you can simply add datalabels to the chart and then format them to display the percentage.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference:

To display the results of a pie chart (probably for other chart types aswell),

1. Right click the actual chart.
2. Click on "format datalabels"
3. On the right sidebar disselect every checkbox except "Percentage"

Hope this comes in handy for future readers

Answer (score 0):

You can just start from your basic data (without the subtotals) and insert a pivot chart (fill in the required fields in thePivotChart Fields). Once you've done that (generally it will look like a histogram), you change the chart type to `pie`.

Comment: i think you misunderstood the question. i already got the pie. the only thing needed was displaying the result as percentage relative to total